# Stack Exchange app for Android not recognizing my suspended account

Tags: bug, mobile-app, network-wide-suspension

How do I associate my suspended account with the app that I am using now? I have a network-wide suspension but I do not want to extend it by using this app to read until my suspension is over.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the apps are no longer relevant due to them being deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Comment: Huh. So weird. Two different @Rob's each with a different close reason. lol

Comment: Anyhow, Rob the II, we don't close old questions as duplicate of that, only new. (As far as I can tell, there's no rule set in stone about it)

Comment: @Sha, the duplicate is [less than a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/348075/1) asked after this question, and not that *long* ago; as there was a period of time where no answers about the APP where being offered, there was faint hope it would be revived. - All mobile-app tagged questions get duped to that since it was written for that purpose by @ sonic.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to associate your suspended account with the app. You can use both the Android and iOS app **without** logging in; once you try something that requires being registered, the app will ask you to log in. Just don't, and reading the Q&A works well enough without having an account. Or use your phone's browser and enjoy the new responsive design...

[image]